# Logic issues in asp+mysql

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, logic

I have a logic problem.
I have some clients, in a MySQL database table.
The client number is the primary key.
Here are some examples of client numbers (ex: 10127, 8520053).

I'm using asp and I want to insert this in a table(array) and use the client number as the index.Like you may noticed 8520053 is to big for a table and makes an out of memory error.

I'm trying to find a formula or whatever you can suggest that can make the client number unique and small enough to fit in a table(array) to use as an index.

I also have the client number in other tables so that formula has to work from table to table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want associative arrays in ASP (like PHP has built-in). ASP has no built-in associative arrays, but you can build them yourself. Here's an example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15465/Bulilding-PHP-like-associative-array-in-ASP

This way, you don't need to perform a transformation on your client id to use it as array index, it's just done transparently by your associative arrays implementation.

Comment: Not sure if that solves my problem.It's a 2 dimension array that will have around 3000 or more results, I also need to do sorting.How will I go in doing those things with associative arrays?

Comment: Sorting is trivial: you just sort the list of keys. The dimension or size is not an issue, any implementation is recursive by default: what is exaclty keeping you from having an associative array of associative arrays of associative arrays... n times deep?

Comment: after some research, I think associative arrays is exactly what I was looking for.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Scripting.Dictionary](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_dictionary.asp) class.

Comment: I've been searching around and found my solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @Alex: Don't just leave this question hanging share your solution as an answer here.

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be multidimensional, Arrays can. Since he needs a 2 dimensional solution with sorting, it's probably better to implement associative arrays. It's just a few lines...

Comment: Everything I need it to do was feasable with dictionnaries.

Comment: @elcodedocle:  How does an "associative array" differ from a "dictionary"?

Comment: In this particular case, the class Scripting.Dictionary is not a multidimensional implementation, that's what I meant :)

Comment: (Although based on the description given I don't see why it has to be multidimensional. This requirement was mentioned later on the comments.)